# OData - how to exclude empty items from result

Tags: swagger, odata

I have below OData query:

```
http://myApp/odata/Suppliers?$expand=SkillTasks($filter=TaskId eq 14)&$select=Id,Name
```

I get all Suppliers. Included SkillTasks are with Id=14 only or empty if given Supplier doesn't have SkillTask with Id=14.

What I expect is: only Suppliers having SkillTask with Id=14. If given Supplier doesn't have SkillTask with Id=14 he/she shouldn't be returned.

I think I should use filter on Supplier instead on SkillTasks but I dont know how to reference to SkillTask there

```
http://myApp/odata/Suppliers?$filter=(SkillTasks.TaskId eq 14)&$expand=SkillTasks&$select=Id,Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that `$filter` inside `$expand` will work but you can use `$filter` with `any` operator.

```
http://myApp/odata/Suppliers?$expand=SkillTasks&$filter=SkillTasks/any(r:r/TaskId eq 14)&$select=Id,Name
```